# First Time Ruby Jekyll Bundler Setup on 16.04 - multiple bundlers installed

Tags: 16.04, ruby, jekyll

I'm trying to get up and running with ruby and the jekyll gem on my fresh instance of Ubuntu 16.04.

```
    usernamehere@usernamehere-hp:~/workspace/username.github.io$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/bundler
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 498 Apr 18 18:18 /usr/local/bin/bundler
    usernamehere@usernamehere-hp:~/workspace/username.github.io$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/bundle
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 497 Apr 18 18:18 /usr/local/bin/bundle
    usernamehere@usernamehere-hp:~/workspace/username.github.io$ ls -la /usr/bin/bundle
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 590 Mar 13  2016 /usr/bin/bundle
    usernamehere@usernamehere-hp:~/workspace/username.github.io$ ls -la /usr/bin/bundler
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 590 Mar 13  2016 /usr/bin/bundler
```

But I seem to have 2 or 4 copies of the ruby gem bundler installed. This is giving me conflicting things when I do things like:

`bundle update` vs `sudo bundle update` and `bundle exec jekyll serve` vs. `sudo bundle exec jekyll serve`

I'm also getting conflicting responses when I run `bundle update` vs `bundler update` vs `sudo bundle update` vs `sudo bundler update`.

What the heck is going on? I don't mind keeping only the ones in `/usr/bin` but I don't know if I should be using `bundle` or `bundler` or how to unsintall the entries in `/usr/local/bin`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you used `sudo apt install ruby` to get ruby in your system.
Which unfortunately is outdated and not the best way to use ruby.

Try completely purging your current ruby and re-installing it using either `rvm` or `rbenv`

You'll find a step by step guide [here](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04).

PS: [You should never run bundler as ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437817/dont-run-bundler-as-root-what-is-the-exact-difference-made-by-using-root), [Completely removing all gems from system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095209/uninstall-all-installed-gems-in-osx).

Comment: My intention was to use the pre-existing ruby installation, if there is one, that comes with ubuntu. I wasn't keen on working with `rvm` or `rbenv` just to use jekyll since personally I'm not a fan of ruby and don't want to overcomplicate things just to write blog posts but it looks like I might not have a better option.

Comment: I see. Did you follow [these procedures](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-jekyll-development-site-on-ubuntu-16-04) ?

Comment: I didn't unfortunately I just ran `bundle exec jekyll serve` until I stopped getting error messages. I've gotten rather comfortable with the package manager so I was confident that I would get it right. I was unfortunately not aware that there is a `bundler` and a `bundle` and I wasn't ready for the package manager to install things to `/usr/local/bin` when they already existed in `usr/bin`. Maybe that's my fault thought.

Comment: How would I purge all instances of ruby / bundle / bundler from my system? `sudo apt-get purge ruby bundle bundler` ?

Comment: Bundler is a gem, you can uninstall it by running `gem uninstall bundler && sudo gem uninstall bundler`, to remove all installed gems run `gem uninstall --all && sudo gem uninstall --all` to purge ruby run `sudo apt purge ruby`.

Comment: If you're doing a clean install of jekyl, i would suggest to follow the [digital ocean's guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-jekyll-development-site-on-ubuntu-16-04), it's the most hassle free (no rvm, rbenv) way.

Comment: thank you I will definitely give that a try this weekend Sirajus